# Click button on remote Div | CasperJS

Tags: javascript, html, casperjs

I am trying to automate a process using CasperJS which requires clicking a button in a remote Div. My main page will have only mentioning of the remote div and the button is present inside the remote div.

main page:

```
<div id= "main_container"></div>
```

remote div:

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="agenda_items">
        <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to click the Click Me button from the casperjs script that runs from main page. I was able to do it when the page used iframe by using `this.switchToChildFrame`/`this.withFrame`. Is there any similar way with Divs also? If it's not possible with CasperJS, is there any other possibility? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to "switch" to a div. Simply determine an appropriate CSS selector or XPath expression that matches the button you're trying to click. Then you can use `casper.click`. If you have problems with that, then please [edit] your question to include your code.

Comment: could you make it an answer so that I can approve it :) Thanks.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "switch" to a div. Simply determine an appropriate CSS selector or XPath expression that matches the button you're trying to click. Then you can use casper.click

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly then you have two options:

1. Use jQuery inside of an evaluate method to click the button you're referring to.

   Maybe something like this:

   ```
   casper.evaluate(function() {
       $('button:contains("Click Me")').click();
   }
   ```
2. Use the [clickLabel](http://casperjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/casper.html#clicklabel) method that's built into Casper

   ```
   casper.then(function() {
       this.clickLabel('Click Me!', button);
   });
   ```

Comment: This is not working because the button I want to click is not in the main page but in other page. The casperjs isnt able to find the button.

Comment: And you can't navigate to that page? Do you have an example URL?